# How to unhide a contact address in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-contacts

I accidentally hid a contact on Google Maps, thereby removing his/her address on the map. How do I undo this action?

Comment: If you check your contact in question inside Google Contacts, is the address still there?  As far as I know, you can just add their address back into the contact card and it will show up on maps.

Comment: @CzarMatt Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and re-adding the contact, this seems to be the most recommended workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to solutions given [Google Maps Help forum](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST8RFzqQ_EP2q0/?hl=en), you can try **deleting** the contact and then **re-adding** it.

> It is presumed that these settings are  stored in the Contacts App on your
>   phone, not the Maps app.

Thus perfoming the above mentioned workaround will then override the "hide" option.

Additionally you may need to resync the information to Google servers.

Answer (score 0):

My solution just recently when I hide contact by accident

Settings-Apps-Google Maps-Force shutdown- Clear memory + cache
Start maps again and the contacts should be back.

Answer (score 0):

Open location sharing (from the menu in the top left corner of the Google maps app). You should see a list of everyone who has shared their location with you, including the one you accidentally hid from the map. Select that person, and an option should appear for you to "show on map". Select that, and they will again appear on your map.

Answer (score 0):

on the maps app, click on your profile picture located at the right side of the search bar, then "location sharing", then click on the 3 dots in the top right corner and "hidden from map (1)" where 1 is the number of hidden contacts. Then, click on the 3 dots of the contact that you want to unhide, and click on "show on map". Now your contact's location will be shown on the map again.